# Windows Free File Utility to copy file with folder structure?

Tags: windows, fileutils

I am looking for free utilities which will copy the file which i want along with the folder structure.

Does anyone aware of any file utility? I couldn't find except winzip which is payable.

Thanks,
Kathir

Comment: not a programming-question.

Comment: Copy / Paste from Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's built-in:

```
robocopy /mir c:\source d:\dest
```

robocopy has [many other options too](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As Sweko said in his comment you can copy/paste in Windows Explorer.

Or in cmd.exe:

> `xcopy /e source destination`